# Angular material datepicker - blank popup in prod

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

Not sure what I am missing. This works fine in when I run it in my local using ng build and ng serve

But when I moved to production, it started behaving like this. Then I tried to reproduce in my local using `ng build --prod` and `ng serve --prod`. Now I can reproduce the issue in my local as well.

What I want: the datepicker popup should appear with correct styling and should be able to select date

What is working now: in local it is working with ng build and ng serve

What is the issue: in prod (or using `ng build --prod` and `ng serve --prod`), the popup shows empty. please the below picture

What I have tried: After researching I found some suggestions to try out with `ng serve --prod --build-optimizer=false` also tried by making `"buildOptimizer": false` in `angular.json`

Erro: When I click on the datepicker icon, I can below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of
```

Please let me know what more information is required to debug this issue. I was thinking of creating a stackblitz, but it seems to be working in stackblitz.

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^10.1.0",
    "angular-google-charts": "^0.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^5.2.6",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.0.3",
    "ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.1.8",
    "ng4-charts": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ngx-spec": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
```

html:

```
        <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>From Date</mat-label>
                <input  [value]="date.value" matInput [matDatepicker]="summBoardFromDatePicker"  placeholder="From Date" [(ngModel)]="summBoardFromDate">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle  matSuffix [for]="summBoardFromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #summBoardFromDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting empty popup on local machine . Can you  share your workArounf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a defect in material datepicker. Not a solution, but a workaround that worked for me.
Can you try making below changes in your `angular.json`

```
"optimization": false
"aot": false
"buildOptimizer": false
```

Comment: Yes, seems to be an workaround. I will go with this solution for now